# OSError: [Errno 99] error while attempting to bind on address cannot assign requested address

Tags: python-3.x, alibaba-cloud

I'm getting this message when running code in Alibaba Free Elastic IP:

```
OSError: [Errno 99] error while attempting to bind on address ('147.139.5.81', 31333): cannot assign requested address
```

Here is the code which is correctly working in Amazon  EC2:'

```
ip = '147.139.5.81' #In Amazon EC2, ip will be different

    start_server = websockets.serve(
        hello, ip, 31333
    )

    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

`ifconfig -a shows`:

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.31.173.211  netmask 255.255.240.0  broadcast 172.31.175.255
        ether 00:16:3e:01:30:8e  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 473419  bytes 267646492 (267.6 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 309017  bytes 92824868 (92.8 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 72620  bytes 4035134 (4.0 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 72620  bytes 4035134 (4.0 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

% `dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com` shows:

147.139.5.81

What could be the problem? I've sshed to this VPS using ip: 147.139.5.81

Answer (score 0):

You must be using a VPC network type ECS instance because inet of your ECS instance is a private IP. For VPC network type ECS instances, the public IP of the ECS instance is not visible inside the OS, hence you cannot bind it.

You can bind 0.0.0.0 and use security groups of ECS instance to allow/block traffic toward the ECS.

Comment: Is there any way in which I can make the public IP of the instance visible to the OS?

Answer (score 0):

I have VPS is not Amazon.  ip = '0.0.0.0'  it works for me